# Unity Android APK crashing on startup

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, logcat

OK, so since I last successfully built, all I have done is tried adding Google Play Services to my game, from [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity).

I imported the unity package, and setup the google play games for android in the relevant setup window.

I tried building at this point, however I was unable to, recieved that strange error whilst building dex files signifying there being a conflict between aar files. I narrowed it down to being caused by both assets/plugins/android/play-services-base-9.0.2 and assets/plugins/android/play-services-basement-9.0.2.

I unchecked both of these being built to android to have the conversion to dex error stuff go away. I assumed this would be OK.

I then pushed the app onto Google Play, (alpha environment) along with a small controller script for Google Play to login on start():

```
void Awake()
{
    // recommended for debugging:
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    // Activate the Google Play Games platform
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
}

void Start()
{
    Login();
}

void Login()
{
    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
        LoggedIn = success;
    });
}
```

However Unity appears to be crashing before opening the first scene. It is crashing right away, upon startup. The logcat stuff can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/vJnfx5fs).

The problem appears to occur around line 842:

```
10-07 06:03:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(9551): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 06:03:06.298: W/ActivityManager(771):   Force finishing activity 1 com.PINGUAPPS.TEMPLATE/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity
10-07 06:03:06.339: W/ActivityManager(771):   Force finishing activity 2 com.google.android.apps.mtaas.backdrop/.BackdropActivity
10-07 06:03:06.402: D/Atlas(771): Validating map...
```

I have no idea how to fix this?

**::Additional Info::**

So I have rolled back to a point where I have the unity package imported into Unity, but I haven't configured it yet, giving it my xml containing the resources. It is giving a nullreferenceexception in the editor at this point:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.OnPostprocessAllAssets (System.String[] importedAssets, System.String[] deletedAssets, System.String[] movedAssets, System.String[] movedFromAssetPaths) (at Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor/PlayServicesResolver.cs:104)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222)
Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:232)
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:115)
UnityEditor.AssetPostprocessingInternal.PostprocessAllAssets (System.String[] importedAssets, System.String[] addedAssets, System.String[] deletedAssets, System.String[] movedAssets, System.String[] movedFromPathAssets) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssetPostprocessor.cs:27)
UnityEditor.AssetDatabase:Refresh()
GooglePlayGames.Editor.GPGSUpgrader:.cctor() (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/GPGSUpgrader.cs:107)
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:SetLoadedEditorAssemblies(Assembly[])
```

The line it references is:

```
if (!Resolver.ShouldAutoResolve(importedAssets, deletedAssets,
                movedAssets, movedFromAssetPaths))
```

However right after this nullreferenceexception, I see the resolver being registered in the logs. Such as:

```
Registering resolver version 1.2.0
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_2:.cctor() (at Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor/ResolverVer1_2.cs:34)
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:SetLoadedEditorAssemblies(Assembly[])
```

etc.

Now, I can build this APK and run it on my phone fine, no problems. (Obviously google play game services won't do much, as it isn't configured).

So, I go to Window >> Google Play Games >> Setup >> Android
and here, I paste my resources XML.
I give a place and name for the resources C# file, and hit Setup.

I see the following Jar Dependency Conflict options:

```
Remove or replace play-services-ads version 9.0.2 with version 9.6.1?
Remove or replace support-v4 version 23.1.1 with version 24.0.0?
Remove or replace play-services-gcm version 9.0.2 with version 9.6.1?
Remove or replace play-services-location version 9.0.2 with version 9.6.1?
Remove or replace play-services-base version 9.0.2 with version 9.6.1?
Remove or replace play-services-basement version 9.0.2 with version 9.6.1?
Remove or replace support-annotations version 23.1.1 with version 23.4.0?
Remove or replace play-services-iid version 9.0.2 with version 9.6.1?
Remove or replace play-services-tasks version 9.0.2 with version 9.6.1?
```

I have tried pressing keep to all of these as well as OK, both actions end up causing a conflict with my aars.

I just tried again, this time pressing OK to all of them, and attempted to build again having only done this since my last successful build. Whilst converting the jars to dex format, it fails the build giving the following error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\java.exe -Xmx1024M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/PINGU/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.a) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.banners.BannerSize$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.banners.b) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.banners.d) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.banners.a) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.banners.c) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.interstitials.a.b) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.interstitials.a.c) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.ofw.a) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.a) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.a.e) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.a.f) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.a.g) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.a.h) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.a.d) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.a.i) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.a.j) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.a.m) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.a.n) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.a.o) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.b) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.c) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.e) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.h) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.f) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.g) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.k) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.i) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.j) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.fyber.ads.videos.l) that doesn't come with<message truncated>
```

As mentioned previously, I can prevent this from happening by locating my play-services-base and play-services-basement files and unchecking them to be built for android. When I do this the APK builds, however the app will crash as soon as its opened.

Comment: Could you list the aar conflict error? that would be helpful.

Comment: Added as much additional information as I could think of - Hope this helps :)

Comment: If you have eclipse, just use logcat to see the errors on launching app.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem last year on my Android game project. I updated Android Support Repository ,Android Support Library , Google Play Services, Google Repository , Google Billing Library, Android API 6.0 , and then the problem is solved. I still don't know what the source of problem is but, I solved the problem with this way in my project. I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with my unity project a while back. Was a duplicate support-v4 class. Figured out it was best to import google play plugin into an empty project ( Do a test build ).

Then completely remove the google play plugin and all files from Extensions, Editor and Plugins folders and re-import from the empty project. Sorry, I can't clarify further any longer have access to my project files.

Answer (score 0):

In case, If you haven't added the Google Admob ADs ID in the inspector, will also cause the app to crash at the beginning in most cases.